# Long or background callbacks in django-plotly-dash

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, callback, plotly-dash

I have been using the django-plotly-dash package lately and was wondering if I could implement a progress bar for a very long-running task of my app.

Below I have the demo-version of the progress bar I would like to implement. Is it even possible in the django-plotly-dash package? If not does anyone have any suggestions how I should deal with that?

I'm very thankful for any replies helping since I'm kinda stuck...

```
import time
import os

import dash
from dash import DiskcacheManager, CeleryManager, Input, Output, html

if 'REDIS_URL' in os.environ:
    # Use Redis & Celery if REDIS_URL set as an env variable
    from celery import Celery
    celery_app = Celery(__name__, broker=os.environ['REDIS_URL'], backend=os.environ['REDIS_URL'])
    background_callback_manager = CeleryManager(celery_app)

else:
    # Diskcache for non-production apps when developing locally
    import diskcache
    cache = diskcache.Cache("./cache")
    background_callback_manager = DiskcacheManager(cache)

app = dash.Dash(__name__, background_callback_manager=background_callback_manager)

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.Div(
            [
                html.P(id="paragraph_id", children=["Button not clicked"]),
                html.Progress(id="progress_bar", value="0"),
            ]
        ),
        html.Button(id="button_id", children="Run Job!"),
        html.Button(id="cancel_button_id", children="Cancel Running Job!"),
    ]
)

@dash.callback(
    output=Output("paragraph_id", "children"),
    inputs=Input("button_id", "n_clicks"),
    background=True,
    running=[
        (Output("button_id", "disabled"), True, False),
        (Output("cancel_button_id", "disabled"), False, True),
        (
            Output("paragraph_id", "style"),
            {"visibility": "hidden"},
            {"visibility": "visible"},
        ),
        (
            Output("progress_bar", "style"),
            {"visibility": "visible"},
            {"visibility": "hidden"},
        ),
    ],
    cancel=Input("cancel_button_id", "n_clicks"),
    progress=[Output("progress_bar", "value"), Output("progress_bar", "max")],
    prevent_initial_call=True
)
def update_progress(set_progress, n_clicks):
    total = 5
    for i in range(total + 1):
        set_progress((str(i), str(total)))
        time.sleep(1)

    return f"Clicked {n_clicks} times"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would be interested in exactly the same question: how to use long/background callbacks with django-plotly-dash?